# how to implement filter in posts in ghost blog

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I am working on a blog. On the homepage, it has a bootstrap slider at the top followed by posts after it.

So, first 3 latest posts will appear in the slider and from 4th post onwards, they will appear in the rest of the markup.

I think I need to implement some kind of filter which would do the deed.

Below is my **hbs** code.

```
<div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner ">
            <div class="item active ">
                {{#foreach posts}}
                <article class="{{post_class}} col-md-12">
                    <div class="post-inner">
                        <header class="post-header text-left">
                            <h2 class="post-title "><a href="{{url}}">{{{title}}}</a></h2>
                        </header>
                        <section class="post-excerpt">
                            <p>{{excerpt words="20"}} <a class="read-more" href="{{url}}">&raquo;</a></p>
                            {{#if image}}<img class="post-image" src="{{image}}" alt="Post image" />{{/if}}
                        </section>
                        <div class="post-meta">
                            {{#if author.image}}<img class="author-thumb" src="{{author.image}}" alt="Author image" nopin="nopin" />{{/if}} {{author}} {{tags prefix=" on "}}
                            <time class="post-date" datetime="{{date format='YYYY-MM-DD'}}">{{date format="DD MMMM YYYY"}}</time>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                {{/foreach}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        {{#foreach posts}}
        <article class="{{post_class}} col-md-12">
            <div class="post-inner">
                <header class="post-header text-left">
                    <h2 class="post-title "><a href="{{url}}">{{{title}}}</a></h2>
                </header>
                <section class="post-excerpt">
                    <p>{{excerpt words="20"}} <a class="read-more" href="{{url}}">&raquo;</a></p>
                    {{#if image}}<img class="post-image" src="{{image}}" alt="Post image" />{{/if}}
                </section>
                <div class="post-meta">
                    {{#if author.image}}<img class="author-thumb" src="{{author.image}}" alt="Author image" nopin="nopin" />{{/if}} {{author}} {{tags prefix=" on "}}
                    <time class="post-date" datetime="{{date format='YYYY-MM-DD'}}">{{date format="DD MMMM YYYY"}}</time>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        {{/foreach}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope I made my question clear.

Comment: Is this [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)? I am not familiar with a Handlebars `#foreach`, only an `#each`.

Comment: @76484 hi, yes this handlebars.

Comment: Do you have access to the back-end? Could you not split the `posts` into two collections - one for the slider and one for the listing?

Comment: @76484 its all on my local. Project isn't live. 

i am sorry I do not follow you. if you can elaborate

Comment: I am asking whether you are able to modify the data on the server, for example, changing the 'posts' object.

Comment: oh yea. I can..

Comment: I wonder how you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to modify the back-end code that creates the template data object, then I think it would be preferable to perform the grouping logic *before* the data is passed to the template.

Assuming you have an array of blog posts which you are passing to your view:

```
{
    posts: array_of_posts
}
```

You could instead have two arrays in your template data, one for the slider and one for the listing:

```
{
    slider_posts: array_of_posts.slice(0, 3),
    listing_posts: array_of_posts.slice(3)
}
```

In your template, you will then iterate over `slider_posts` and `listing_posts` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **limit** in your #foreach loop for slider and use **from** and **to** to set start and end point of your posts.

```
{{#foreach posts from="0" to="4" limit="4"}}
....
{{/foreach}}
```